# <list> retreving items problem with iterator

Tags: c++, function, class, g++, compiler-errors

I have a list of type Instruction*. Instruction is a class that I made. This class has a function called execute().

I create a list of Instruction*

```
list<Instruction*> instList;
```

I create an Instruction*

```
Instruction* instPtr;
instPtr = new Instruction("test",10);
```

If I call

```
instPtr.execute();
```

the function will be executed correctly, however if I store instPtr in the instList I cannot call the execute() function anymore from the list.

```
//add to list
instList.push_back(instPtr);

//create iterator for list
list<Instruction*>::iterator p = instList.begin();
//now p should be the first element in the list
//if I try to call execute() function it will not work
p -> execute();
```

I get the following error:

```
error: request for member ‘execute’ in ‘* p.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator-> [with _Tp = Instruction*]()’, which is of non-class type ‘Instruction*’
```

Comment: John Kugelman pretty explained what the issue is, but please keep in mind that storing a pointer in an STL container is a resource leak waiting to happen unless you've got separate code to clean up the Instruction objects you created. Any specific reason why you're storing pointers to them rather than the objects themselves?

Comment: If `intrPtr` really is a pointer then I don't believe that `instPtr.execute()` will compile, let alone execute the function correctly. Can you check your posted code?

Comment: @Timo: when dealing with inheritance, storing pointers is the way to go, though I agree that using Boost pointer containers would probably be better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`p` is an iterator of `Instruction *` pointers. You can think of it as if it were of type `Instruction **`. You need to double dereference `p` like so:

```
(*p)->execute();
```

`*p` will evaluate to an `Instruction *`, and further applying the `->` operator on that will dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

try `(*p)->execute();`

Comment: Sadly (well, actually it's probably a good thing) you can't use `p->->execute();` for this

Answer (score 1):

Instead of p->execute() you need (*p)->execute();

You need to de-reference the list iterator to get the value associated with the node in the list referenced by your iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is keep boost::shared_ptr in your list. Remember all STL containers working with copy principle.

Use this code

list > instList;

then call your execute function as usual

instList[i]->execute();

as you can see you call execute as you keep pointers in your list. this is the best solution

Comment: The question is not about resource management. Your code works only because you used the std::list::operator[]

Comment: I didn't say you cannot use it. The problem the OP had had nothing to do with the pointer type. It was having dereferenced the iterator only once instead of twice. your solution dereferenced the iterator twice: once by calling operator[] and the other by using ->. It would have worked even if you used a built-in pointer just the same (although not doing what the OP requested: using begin())